# Instantiate C++ class in Android project with libgdx

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin

We have to dev a little mobile game (android / iOS). We use the ligdx for the android app.
The AI is coded with C++ (same code on iOS and Android). For the native part, we create an android.mk and application.mk to generate a lib .so. But we cannot instanciate our native class. 
We will use the NDK to put the C++ classes on our Android App.
We have some mistake...
We have take example from the google samples, and with their method we cannot use the libgdx, because when we create the project with GDX, it generate some things on the config files (build.gradle:app, build.gradle). And when we use 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0' gradle not recognizes the package 'android' make by GDX.
And when i use 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1', gradle not recognizes android.ndk.

build.gralde (Project Root)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'
    }
    /*repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url"https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
    }*/
}

allprojects {
   apply plugin: "eclipse"
   apply plugin: "idea"

   version = '1.0'
   ext {
    appName = "Gomoku"
    gdxVersion = '1.7.1'
    roboVMVersion = '1.9.0'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
    ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
    aiVersion = '1.6.0'
   }

   repositories {
      mavenCentral()
      maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
      maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
   }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
       compile project(":core")
       compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
       natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
       natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
       natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
       compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
       natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
       natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
       natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java"


    dependencies {
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    }
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
     delete ".project"
}
```

How can we combine the both libGDX and ndk (like Google's samples)

Thanks

Comment: Sorry we are French...

Comment: the title states: "Intanciate C++ class in Android" it is almost imposlible without factory method written in C ... but then ... AFAIK JNI bridge doesn't support imports function with `thiscall`calling convention ... so the only way is to wrap C++ code into C code which can be used with JNI bridge

Comment: ... but if real problem is with ndk support in gradle configuration then you should look [here](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental)

Comment: ok thank you @Selvin

Comment: But when i use the gradle-experimental i have a problem with 'apply plugin: "android"'.

Error:(32, 0) Plugin with id 'android' not found. This is the libdx.